# Access denied fetching images from amazon s3 with full permissions set

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer-s3

I have updated the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1536491056397",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::gdesign",
                "arn:aws:s3:::gdesign/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But still get `access denied error` when I try to access the image url: https://gdesign.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1536491951672

What else do I need to update on aws?

Comment: Change to `"Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::gdesign", "arn:aws:s3:::gdesign/*"`. You've given access to the bucket or root folder, but not to anything within.

Comment: @Vineet Still the same issue

Comment: probably looks like you have mixed IAM and Bucket Policy. Try using this: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the correct region while creating bucket fixed my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by correct region? I didn't understand how you could select an in-correct region.

Comment: I'm also curious about this, seems like if I choose a region for the aws object, i get a proper url but access denied

Comment: @jones Choose your region(country) while selecting the region in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Im using PHP S3 lib, version 3.82.5, i got access defined when show img in webside too, my solution is when get img url from S3, u may need to call "createPresignedRequest" (Create a pre-signed URL for the given S3 command object) this function. Then every thing will be fine.